# Trouble programmatically changing routes with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having a lot of trouble trying to navigate with React Router programmatically.  I can change routes once, but I cannot change routes twice.

I keep receiving the error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

You can see my code here: http://codepen.io/vpt/pen/bpyjoN

```
moveOver: function(){
  this.props.history.push('wow');
},
render: function(){
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.moveOver}>Goodbye!</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

My code stops working when I click on the button that fires the moveOver function.  It is supposed to move to a third route.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link you gave for your code, it is breaking because the Test3 component isn't defined properly. In the render function you are not returning.

should be like this:

```
var Test3 = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return(
        <div>Wow!</div>
    );
  }
});
```

that will fix the issue.

Comment: Well.. that's embarrassing. Thank you!